# Espaço em branco na lateral site mobile na ver são mobile o site fica com um lateral branca, link do site http://deivilydias.github.io/

Tags: html, css

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    #menu {
        visibility: hidden;
    } 
    #titulo{
        font-size: 65px
    }
    #imagem_fundo{
        background-position: center;
    }
    .colunas, .lateral, .lateral_3, .lateral_4 {
         display: block;   
         width: 85%;
         padding: 5%;
         margin: 0px;
         float: none;
    }
    #acao {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A Lateral branca está ocorrendo por dois motivos:

Elemento `button` de `id="acao"`, ele está com a propriedade `visibility="hidden"`, essa propriedade esconde o elemento em tela porém mantém sua posição na árvore de elementos DOM, com isso está empurrando seu contéudo para o lado. Mude para `display="none"`.

Dentro da `section` de `id="part_4"`, especificamente na propriedade `width="120%"` da imagem, se tratando de versão mobile, talvez o ideal seja você manter essa propriedade como 100% para evitar a quebra.

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!!